# Tag doesn't work when object is a child of the camera?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject with the tag 'right' when this gameobject isn't a child of the camera, it gets recognised with this:

```
if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "right")
```

However, when I make the gameobject a child of the camera (which i need to do) it is no longer recognised. Any ideas on what I can do?

Full code is:

```
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {

        Vector2 pos = new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        RaycastHit2D hitInfo = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (pos), Vector2.zero);
        Debug.Log (pos); // space indication
        // we have something under our pointer
        if (hitInfo) {
            if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "left") {
                playerMovement += Vector2.left * distance; // do something
            }
            if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "right") {
                playerMovement += Vector2.left * distance; // or do something else
            // (...)
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you debug it and look at what is assigned to `hitInfo.transform.gameObject`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to check the children then?

```
if (hitInfo.transform.Cast<Transform>()
    .Any(child => child.gameObject.tag == "left")
    playerMovement += Vector2.left * distance; // do something

if (hitInfo.transform.Cast<Transform>()
    .Any(child => child.gameObject.tag == "right")
    playerMovement -= Vector2.left * distance; // or do something else
```